# how to count and group by using linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, count

I want count the production and grouping by location id and sdmaterial, but its error

```
Prodution = productionLala.Where(n => n.Date >= x.StartDate && n.Date < x.EndDate)
                          .GroupBy(n => n.From_Location_ID && n.SDMaterial_Group)
                          .Select(n.production).Count();
```

can someone help me? :) thx

Comment: What is `Production`? what is `n.production`? what is the expected output? please give an example - it will be easier to understand

Comment: Also what is the purpose of counting? Do you want to know how many groups you have? If so why select `n.production` first - it will still be one item per group? Did you maybe mean `sum`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to retrieve `Count` for per `From_Location_ID` and `SDMaterial_Group`.

```
var groupCounts = productionLala.Where(n => n.Date >= x.StartDate && n.Date < x.EndDate)
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.From_Location_ID,
        x.SDMaterial_Group
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        From_Location_ID = x.Key.From_Location_ID,
        SDMaterial_Group = x.Key.SDMaterial_Group,
        Count = x.Count()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this may be this will work-

```
var Prodution = productionLala.Where(n => n.Date >= x.StartDate && n.Date < 
x.EndDate).GroupBy(x => new{ x.From_Location_ID , x.SDMaterial_Group})
.Select(n.production).count();
```

Comment: @Gilad Green- why not ?

Comment: First of all because your current code doesn't compile, you do not know what `Production` is and you do not know what is the expected output ..

Comment: ya you are correct Gilad . Thank You Brother.
I thought it will help someone .